# SQL SERVER Query result performance question

Tags: networking, sql-server-2005, sql

When I run a simple query on server SSMS it takes 3 seconds. When I run the same query on my computer on SSMS it takes 35 seconds. What could be the reason? What should I check first?
I tried disable the antivirus samething.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is if the execution plans are same or NOT. And then next thing is to check the connection properties from both the machines. The below whitepaper might help you there.

http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: What happens if you run the same query for second time from your computer. Does it still take 35 seconds or runs quicker?

Comment: It takes same time always I don't think it is caching anything...

Comment: Caching the data pages is a server concept and it is done automatically by SQL Server whether the request is coming from the server or from a different client. How simple is the query and can you share the execution plans from both?

Comment: Seems like index is messed up. What is the safest way to rebuild/reorgznize the indexes when many users are online?

Comment: If you have enterprise edition then you can use ONLINE flag to build the index online otherwise try reorganizing the index (which is slow, and NOT as effective as REBUILD).